# wysiwyg editor compatible with atlassian jira

Tags: angular, editor, jira, wysiwyg

I need to provide an external system that updates jira issues, and one of the stumbling blocks that I have is the "rich text" editor that jira uses. The text appears to be some form of custom text markup, and I believe that the editor they use is tinymce

To make it worse, I am using angular-cli / angular2/4 ;)

Does anyone know of an editor widget that I can use that is both wysiwyg and jira text-formatting compatible ?

I have tried quill, tinymce, and various others

Alternatively, a module that has bi-directional conversion between html and jira would also suit my needs (as there are plenty of html editors around ;) )

Ideally, Jira has open-sourced the editor widget (however, I can't find it anywhere)

Comment: We have the same issue did you find any solution?

Comment: afraid not, sorry